# How to include delete function in UpdateView instead a DeleteView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a UpdateView for editing a post, but instead of making a DeleteView for delete a post, i try to make UpdateView include a function to delete the post. So ,i want to edit and delete a post in UpdateView. Is that possible ? i think i missing something in my code so the code keep getting error.

> form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

views.py

```
class PostUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','file','description']
    template_name = 'post/post_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_profile:profile')

    def form_valid(self, form, pk):
        if 'confirm_post' in self.request.POST:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        elif 'confirm_delete' in self.request.POST:
            post_delete = PostModel.objects.get(pk = id)
            post_delete.delete()
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path
app_name = 'post'

urlpatterns = [
    url('user_post/', views.PostView.as_view(), name= 'user_post'),
    url('post_list/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name= 'post_detail'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', views.PostUpdate.as_view(), name= 'post_update'),
]
```

post_update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load bootstrap3%}
{% block content %}

  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% bootstrap_form form%}
    <input type="submit" name="confirm_post" value="Confirm">
    <input type="submit" name="confirm_delete" value="Delete">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What or where is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Bott0610 form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `post` method to make it work like below

```
class PostUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','file','description']
    template_name = 'post/post_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_profile:profile')

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if 'confirm_delete' in self.request.POST:
            post_delete = PostModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            post_delete.delete()
        return super(PostUpdate, self).post(request, pk)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if 'confirm_post' in self.request.POST:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank @Anjaneyulu Batta, now my delete function is working fine! but the form_valid for update doesnt working, it just reverse to the user_profile page without any error but the content remain unchange even i edit it .

Comment: @giamzengkeat Yeah, right. It won't work. because it has extra parameter "pk". I've updated the answer. It should work now.

Comment: Actually i spot the extra 'pk' before i run the code, so i remove it before i run, but unfortunately the form_valid(self,form) for updating didnt successfully update the changes, it just reverse to the success_url. But the delete work fine, and i edit the return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form) to return redirect("user_profile:profile"), so it will redirect to the profile page after i delete. Still, thank you for helping me !

Comment: if i use the code you updated without changing anything, the form_valid for update work fine, but the delete function not. but if i change the return super(PostUpdate, self).post(request, pk) to return redirect("user_profile:profile") in the delete function, the delete work fine but the update not working properly anymore. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an old post, but I figured to answer since I solved this problem.

Just utilize the `DeletionMixin` module from `django.generic.edit` file.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView, DeletionMixin


class PostUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, DeletionMixin, UpdateView):
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','file','description']
    template_name = 'post/post_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_profile:profile')



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "confirm_delete" in self.request.POST:
            return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form, pk):
        if 'confirm_post' in self.request.POST:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The `DeletionMixin` will import its `delete` function and handle the rest.  Make sure to overwrite the `post` function or all POST requests will result in deletion.

Comment: it ignore the update functionality when overriding the post. Unable to figure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The line `def form_valid(self, form, pk):` should be `def form_valid(self, form):`. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) don't have form_valid as taking a pk argument. You can get the pk using: `form.instance.pk` instead.

EDIT:

```
class PostUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','file','description']
    template_name = 'post/post_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_profile:profile')

    def form_valid(self, form):

        if 'confirm_post' in self.request.POST:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        elif 'confirm_delete' in self.request.POST:
            pk = form.instance.pk
            post_delete = PostModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            post_delete.delete()
            # Or just one line: form.instance.delete()
        return super(PostUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but how to use the form.instance.pk in my views.py?

Comment: Thank, now my error are gone, but i still cant delete, the post still remaining at  there after i delete.

Comment: Check your POST data for 'confirm_delete'  maybe?